# Prevent PDF from automatically downloading

Tags: php, wordpress, pdf

I'm building a WordPress site for a property lettings agent (real estate), which links to their property management system (LetMC).

LetMC provides PDF property brochures through a URL, for example (ignore the brochure content, yet to be designed):

[https://home.letmc.com/property.brochure?propertybrochure={060a-549c-6de2-8fcf}&Bucket=CubaLive_priestley](https://home.letmc.com/property.brochure?propertybrochure=%7B060a-549c-6de2-8fcf%7D&Bucket=CubaLive_priestley)

I've built a nice system to show property photos, brochure and location using a lightbox through AJAX, and so I don't want to auto-download the PDF. Currently I'm saving the PDF to a temp folder and opening it direct from the sites web server, but ideally I want to avoid saving the PDF....

Is this possible??

**Current progress:**

```
/**
 * Lightbox Brochure
 *
 * Return property brochure to be viewed in a lightbox
 */
public static function lightbox_brochure() {
    $letmc_brochure_url = $_REQUEST['dataurl'];

    if ( isset( $letmc_brochure_url ) ) {

        $filename = generateRandomString() . '.pdf';
        $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();

        if ( wp_mkdir_p($upload_dir['basedir']) ) {
            $file = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/letmc_uploads/temp/' . $filename;
        }

        /**
         * Store in the temp filesystem
         */
        $ch = curl_init($letmc_brochure_url);
        $fp = fopen($file, 'wb');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        $Result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        fclose($fp);

        $output = '';
        $output .= '<div class="lightbox"><iframe src="' . $upload_dir['baseurl'] . '/letmc_uploads/temp/' . $filename . '" width="97%" height="550"></iframe><button title="Close (Esc)" type="button" class="controls mod-close mfp-close"><i class="icon icon-close"></i></button></div>';

        echo $output;

    } else {
        echo '<p>Sorry, no brochure available.</p>';
    }

    die();
}
```

Comment: Do you want to view the pdf online, within your website?

Comment: @GiancarloColfer Within the lightbox ideally, so I'll need a file name for the iframe src. The current system works... but is it best practise? Also, I'm not entirely sure how to deal with a temp folder.... I'd like to remove the PDF after it's viewed, or maybe set up a cron job to empty the folder once a day

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to save the file to show it later. You can simply access the PDF file and spit it out directly into the iframe as this:

Create file **getpdf.php**:

```
$url = urldecode($_GET['url']);
$pdf_data = file_get_contents($url);
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
echo $pdf_data;
```

Ammend your code as this (place it right below`$output = '';`):

`$letmc_brochure_url = urlencode($letmc_brochure_url);`

`$output .= '<div class="lightbox"><iframe src="getpdf.php?url=' . $letmc_brochure_url . '" width="97%" height="550"></iframe><button title="Close (Esc)" type="button" class="controls mod-close mfp-close"><i class="icon icon-close"></i></button></div>';`

The only drawback here is that each time the file is requested, it needs to be downloaded again by the server (there's no caching), which might put some strain on your server resources.

Comment: can't get this working... have tried a similar solution. My AJAX response is the PDFs code. Also, this wouldn't work with my lightbox solution as I need an iframe source. Thanks for the input though

Comment: I've updated the code. Create a new file getpdf.php and paste my code into it. Then, you can invoke it as this: `<iframe src="getpdf.php?url=https://home.letmc.com/property.brochure?propertybrochure={060a-549c-6de2-8fcf}&Bucket=CubaLive_priestley"></iframe>` You might need to` urlencode() / urldecode()` the url to get it work.

Comment: Can you write out the full example please.... I can't how you've come to this solution, looks odd to me

Comment: I've amended the answer. Hope it makes sense now.

Comment: this is giving me an iframe with my 404 page in it :) Sorry, but I don't think you're heading in the right direction

Comment: You are given 404 because you need to enter a full path to getpdf.php file in iframe source e.g. http://www.yourservername.com/path/to/getpdf.php.

Comment: Thanks for your help, going to leave this one... not confident with your solution

Answer (score 0):

Google’s Google Docs has a nifty iframe embed tool that allows you to embed and view documents online (pdf’s included)!

Check out the code below. You simply need to supply the url of the document.

```
<iframe id="app-iframe" class="iframe-doc" src="http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://www.giancarlocolfer.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/pdf-sample.pdf&amp;embedded=true" height="600" width="680" title="PDF Sample" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

You can see a live demo/example of this [PDF and Document Online Reader](http://www.giancarlocolfer.com/blog/pdf-and-document-online-reader-embed-and-view-pdfs-and-documents-free/68/) iframe embed tool over at my professional [web development and design blog](http://www.giancarlocolfer.com/blog/).

Comment: doesn't seem to work with the URLs LetMC provide I'm afraid... would of been a nice solution though :)

Comment: Have you checked the header output of your script? Make sure you are sending out: Content-type: application/pdf then try the google docs iframe embed tool again.